# PHP excel reader error while converting dd/mm/yyyy hr:min:sec

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hi Friends I am using the following piece of code to read a excel sheet which has values like 02/11/2013 15:27:40 but when I am following the method which is show below I am getting an output which is 41580.6442129629. I am not sure what is the error Please Help me to resolve this issue.

```
$this->load->library('excel');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once 'application/third_party/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel5');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($path);
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
$highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); // e.g 'F'
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); // e.g. 5

for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
                            if($col == $date_col)
                            {
                                    $date_column = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
                                    echo $date_column;
                            }
                       }
             }
```

Comment: $date_coulmn returns 41580.6442129629?

Comment: yes :/ it returns decimal value as  41580.6442129629

Comment: Just check with my answer.

Comment: Why not use getFormattedValue() for the date/time cells? or `echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($date_column));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$date_column = new DateTime(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($date_column));
echo $date_column->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Or

```
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($date_column));
```

Comment: $date_column = new DateTime($date_column); there is something wrong with it echo $date_column after this statement is not wrking

Comment: @HackerRocker Check with second option.

Comment: They second one is giving me an output 01/01/1970 00:00:00 which is wrong and the first one isnt wrking

Comment: Second one should be `echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($date_column));` because `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP()` returns a unix timestamp value, not a formatted date string

Comment: @HackerRocker Thanks 4 the Edit..Cheers..:)

Answer (score 0):

In my case no way to obtain date correctly from a EXCEL2007.

So a date in format "3/9/2014 00:00:00" (September) is obtained as "41885".

Studying the format and analogous seems simple a accurate to transform to correct date, with this function:

```
function datefix_excel($excel) {

    $dif=(41885-$excel)*86400;
    $seconds=1409737670-$dif;
    $date=date("d/m/Y",$seconds);
    return $date; }
```

It´s self explanatory. Hope it gives some help.